# Scoping issue with global when called from included file included within a function?

Tags: php, include, scope

I have a file, `standalone.php`, that's meant to be run as its own script, directly from the browser. It defines functions, classes and includes other files. It works fine when directly invoked.

It has code in it like this:

```
$DB = new Database(DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_SERVER, '', true);
function DB() { global $DB; return $DB; }
```

When run alone, $DB is defined in the global name space, and the function that returns the object grabs the global $DB object. Again, this works.

The problem is, i have another file, `sometimesInvoker.php`, that is called from the browser, and in some cases, needs to include standalone.php and output to the browser as if `standalone.php` had been invoked directly. It cannot use a redirect, and it cannot include `standalone.php` via URL.

The code in `sometimesInvoker.php` is:

```
LoadPage();

function LoadPage(){
   include standalone.php;
}
```

So the hierarchy looks like:

```
Global name space / sometimesInvoker.php
   LoadPage() function
      standalone.php - thinks its global but it isn't
         $DB - declared intending to be global but is actually a variable inside LoadPage() function?
            function DB() - calls global DB and looks inside sometimesInvoker.php for a $DB var which isn't there, should be going up one level to LoadPage() function and grabbing that var.
```

So I get the problem, but how to solve it? I need a way for a function to get a variable that is one level above it, regardless of if the next level up is global or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In sometimesInvoker.php make the very first line `require_once 'standalone.php';`

Comment: Depending on what happens in `sometimesInvoker.php`, `standalone.php` may or may not be included at all. The functions in `sometimesInvoker.php` decide if `standalone.php` or `anotherstandalone.php`, etc are included.

Comment: If you include/require standalone within a class, it will always be local to that class. It looks like you're suffering from some poor design decisions. Makes the database connection its own class and inject it into each class that needs it. `$db=new DB();$loadpage=new LoadPage();$loadpage->setDB($db);`

Answer (score 0):

*I need a way for a function to get a variable that is one level above it, regardless of if the next level up is global or not.*

I don't know if i understand you correctly but, there are a few ways of making variables available in sub functions;

Use "global" to use variables in another scope:

```
$db='whatever';
function XXYYY(){
 global $db;
 echo $db;
}
```

Or pass the variables into the function:

```
$db='whatever';
function XXYYY($db){
 echo $db;
}
```

Or am i missing the point?

Comment: In this case, $DB is above the function that needs it, but $DB is not actually in the global name space. $DB is inside a parent function, that is parent to both the $DB var, and the function that needs the $DB var.

Comment: What about using $DB=DB(); inside the subfunction?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I'm using to solve the problem for now. Change the DB() function to:

```
function DB() {
   static $DB = null;
   if(is_null($DB))
      $DB = new Database(DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_SERVER, '', true);
   return $DB;
}
```

Using a static variable in the DB function let's me instantiate the class once instead of relying on a global var. This solves the problem in this case, but I'd still be interested to know if you can access a var outside of a function if that var is in a parent function, not the global namespace?